# jQuery: How can I set css with own width?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to set some labels `right` property so that I can change it on mouse over.

The reason I'm doing this via jQuery is because each one has a different size which doesn't allow to do it via CSS.

This is what I have:

```
$('#vertical-navigation .label').css('right', $(this).width());
```

Which, of course, doesn't work, because `$(this)` is returning what I believe to be the window width.

How can I set the `right` position with the element own width, for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [function parameter](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) like this:

```
$('#vertical-navigation .label').css('right', function(){
    return $(this).width() + 'px';
});
```

Now depending your HTML markup, this could just be enough:

```
$('#vertical-navigation .label').css('right', '100%');
```

Comment: nice, didn't know you could use a function like that

Answer (score 1):

Do it in an each loop then you can use `this`:

```
$('#vertical-navigation .label').each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    label.css('right', label.width() + 'px');
});
```